# The VoIp services certificate works in development

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, voip

I have created two certificates for push notification (one for production and another for development) but when I create a certificate for VoIp notification, is not option for development or production.
The VoIp services certificate works in both environments ?

Answer (score 7):

Actually VoIP Services Certificate is used for both development and production environment, no need to have separate certificates.

I am using the same certificate with
`ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`
and
`ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

Look at this what they say:
[image]

Comment: How can I specify my app in sandbox or production mode? By the DEBUG compile flag?

Comment: the `ssl://..` url you have to change at server side, not in app! so whenever you want to send APN to production build then use 2nd otherwise use first url....

Comment: the question is I don't know how to determine my ad hoc and app store version at the server side

Comment: u have to do it manually... Ideally we've to use test server and production server separately!

Comment: How does Apple decide that it is a VOIP push or normal push?

Comment: @पवन We’ve to add ‘content-available: 1’ in payload at server side, then Apple delivers it silently in background without showing anything in notification centre; which is nothing but a VoIP push

Comment: All silent pushes are not VOIP push.